# Incorrect syntax near '=' error on native query with Spring Boot on Sql Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nativequery

I have an error on the code below, I need to update a series of article with a native query in spring boot to do it I use the code below, however when it executes the code I have the following error, how can I do to fix it ? The error is on the "Sconto" field.

**Error Native Query:**

```
[nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Incorrect syntax near '='.
2022-02-25 09:51:59.045  INFO 29122 --- [nio-8081-exec-1]                                          : Errore importazione METEL: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

**Native Query Code Spring Boot:**

```
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "update Articolo set Prezzo=(PrezzoListino-((PrezzoListino/100) * =:Sconto )) where Importato=:Importato and CodMarca=:CodMarca and FamigliaDiSconto=:FamigliaDiSconto ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Articolo> updateArticoloMetelScontoFirst(@Param("Sconto") Double Sconto, @Param("CodMarca") String CodMarca, @Param("Importato") String Importato, @Param("FamigliaDiSconto") String FamigliaDiSconto);
```

Comment: Remove the `=` next to :Sconto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is pretty descriptive `Incorrect syntax near '='`. In query problem is here

```
...set Prezzo=(PrezzoListino-((PrezzoListino/100) * =:Sconto ))...
```

Remove unwanted `=` before `:Sconto`

```
...set Prezzo=(PrezzoListino-((PrezzoListino/100) * :Sconto ))...
```